# PHP + Cron Job for Fetching Product Prices of 50k Products Each Hour

Tags: php, laravel, curl, cron

I am using cron jobs to fetch the price of around 50k products each hour. A lot of products get skipped during this method.

I have around 50 cron jobs running each minute.
Each Cron Job fetch 10 products in a run and saves price to database.
So around 30k products are being fetched every hour as per calculation. 50*10 = 500/minute -> 500*60 = 30,000/hour
This put a lot of load on my server until it crashes.
Is there any better way to execute this type of cron? 
Is the only option available is PHP's MultiCurl for this type of bulk operation?

Comment: what is the cause of the server crash? Is it about memory usage or Cpu usage? and it is better to share the cron job code.

Comment: @hoseinz3 actually high CPU usage.

Comment: @SukhchainSingh And what about your server configuration?

Comment: How do you update the price of products in your cron job?

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question. You should specify how the data is being retrieved from the remote server.

Comment: @invalidbot Linode's Dedicated CPU Plan, 8 CPU, 16GB RAM.

Comment: @hoseinz3 I'm just pulling 10 products from database in each cron run, using foreach loop + curl it fetches the price, if change in price is found it saves back to database.

Comment: @invalidbot Sorry, I'm just asking if there is better way of implementing this type of bulk operation. I think my way of doing this thing is not good, and needs some optimization.

Comment: How do you manage to get access to the product data? Some kind of APIs or you own that website?

Comment: @invalidbot directly scraping a website and extracting price information from webpage.

Comment: I think it's better to send fewer requests per cron. for example, is it possible to retrieve bulk data from the targeted website?

Comment: Now it makes sense. First of all check if the website provides some APIs or product feeds for third party integration. Scrapping the website is not recommended since it may fail if the HTML changes on the other end.

Comment: Why do you split your cron? is it because of performance or they do a different task?

Comment: If there is no other way, split your process into smaller steps.
First fetch the entire html save it locally. Then scrap it and save the data into an array (say on redis), save it into small chunks and let another script process these chunks. You should consider implementing some sort of queueing here.

Comment: Even further, consider using a separate server for the backend processes if you're not doing so. So that we can avoid the load on the frontend (web front) while processing the data.